# Is it possible to pass an Action delegate to ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
MailMessage message = GetMailMessage();
ProcessEmail(() => SendEmail(message));


private void ProcessEmail(Action Method) {
  try {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(?));
  } catch (Exception ex) {

  }
}


private static void SendEmail(object message) {
  // send email
}
```

My question is, within `ProcessEmail`, can I pass the Action parameter named Method to the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` method?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `Task.Run(Method)` is simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(state=>{Method();}));
```

or more succinctly:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state=>{Method();});
```

Essentially, you are supplying a new anonymous function callback that adapts the call to your `Method()` callback.

Comment: Work well - thanks for that. ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate { Method(); })); also works.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this technique:

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(nameOfAnonymousMethod =>
    {
        Method(...);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use autoresetevent or manualresetevent.

Simple Code:

```
public class Test
{
    private AutoResetEvent _eventWaitThread = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private void Job()
    {
        Action act = () =>
        {
            try
            {
                // do work...
            }
            finally
            {
                _eventWaitThread.Set();
            }
        };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => act());
        _eventWaitThread.WaitOne(10 * 1000 * 60);
    }
}
```